# Chrome taking too much time to upload file comparing to Firefox

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following three lines of code for uploading a file on server:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" name="simple_upload" id="simple_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" id="file_to_upload" name="file_to_upload">
    <input type="submit" id="upload" name="upload" value="Upload" onmouseover="this.focus();">
    </body>
</html>
```

If I upload a 2GB file using Firefox it takes around 30 minutes, while using Chrome takes 2.5 hours to upload the file.

I am using these versions:

Chrome Version: 55.0.2883.87
Firefox Version: 50.1.0

Could someone please give me pointers why it's taking so long with Chrome?

Comment: Is is slow to upload on multiple computers using chrome?

Comment: @Loaf Yes i checked on multiple computers